# How to read data from Excel file in C#?

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I create an Excel file from c# with data validation-it seem like combo with chosen possibility

```
string mList1 = "=ProductCode";
                oRng = oSheet.get_Range("H8", "H9");
                oRng.Name = "ProductCode";
                int t = dt.Rows.Count + 2;
                string st = "F" + t;
                oRng = oSheet.get_Range("F2", st);
                oRng.Validation.Add(XlDVType.xlValidateList, 
                    XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertStop, 
                    Missing.Value, mList1, Missing.Value);
```

Now I want to read the Excel file and also the chosen item from the combo. I have successfully read all the data but the data validation.

Read the data-

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ExcelObj = null;
            ExcelObj = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application(); 
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook theWorkbook = ExcelObj.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Documents and Settings\\rachelg\\My Documents\\xxx.xls"
            ,Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets sheets = theWorkbook.Worksheets;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)sheets.get_Item(1);
            for(int x = 1; x <= 5; x++)
            {  
             string sd = ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)worksheet.Cells[x, 1]).Text.ToString();
                System.Console.WriteLine(sd);//this one column
}
```

in different column I have the data validation but I don't know to access into it.

Comment: Urgent? There isn't a nuke thats going to go off if you don't fix it is there?

Answer (score 0):

That seems a bit much for what is largely a simple operation.

Whilst not answering your question directly, this post I made a while back might help: [accessing data record from Excel in VB.NET](http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2010/01/net/accessing-data-records-from-excel-and-csv-files-in-vb-net).